# What is the ??! operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

when I'm looking for some sites Javascript code, I see this

```
function hrefLeftMenu() {
    var x = true;
    for (i in info) {
        $(".leftmenu ul").append("<li" + (x ? " class='active'" : "") + " onclick='openAnInfo(\"" + i + "\", this);'> - " + info[i].title + "</li>");
        x = x??!x;
    }
    openAnInfo("0", ".lelelesakineyy");
}
```

What it does in javascript? Why the coder's used this operator?

Thanks.

Comment: Strange i had never seen this, Seems like combination of some operators

Comment: Bit confused as to why this has four upvotes. The question requires more information. Is this the exact code you saw? How often have you seen it? Can you provide some of the surrounding code?

Comment: Are you sure about this? I had never seem such syntax!

Comment: I updated the code with a function includes this code, but with the help Quentin provide, I realize code is not working..

Comment: What site did you encounter this on?

Comment: A web service provider's site that we are using in our company. Can't give a link, sorry.

Comment: That's unfortunate. But does it throw an error at all? I'm not sure in what environment this code gets executed - perhaps a proprietary flavour of ECMAScript?

Comment: Folks, we have been alerted - no need for additional flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a mistake. They're generating a menu and `x` is used to set an item as active, and it looks like they want to default to selecting the first item. They want `x` to be true the first time around, and then false for the rest. It was probably supposed to be something like

```
x = x?!x:x; // If first time through, then set x = false for the rest
```

aka

```
x = false; // Set x = false for the rest
```

but confusion/muddy thinking led to over-complification.

Answer (score 12):

> What it does in javascript?

It throws a syntax error.

```
> x = x??!x;
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
```

> Why the coder's used this operator?

Taking a reasonable guess (beyond "they made a mistake") would need more context. Saying for sure would require mind reading :)

Comment: Why I did not check if it is works or not.. Thanks and sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript this is not valid code. However, the sequence `??!` exists (existed?) in C as a [trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C), representing `|`. Maybe that's not JavaScript code, or it was poorly-ported from ancient C code. But even then, `x = x | x` can hardly be called a useful statement.

**EDIT:** With a bit context in the question now, that speculation is likely wrong. A friend suggested that maybe the sequence `x??` was a typo and subsequent attempt to correct it where backspace was turned into a character by some intermediate mangling (not uncommon when typing in terminals or via SSH) and that the line in question was supposed to be `x = !x`.

Answer (score 2):

Was this a mistake?

Did you mean this?

```
x= x?x:!x;
```

Comment: Without the operator, the whole `x` variable is pretty useless in the OP's snippet, so the `??!` probably swaps the value or something. `x?x:!x` is likely not what the author meant.